# Zeroes of polynomials with several variables

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, roots

Just consider a polynomial with multiple variables on the field of real number, **A** is its zeroes set. Is **A** a zero measure set ? How to prove that?

Comment: It's false. Take $P\equiv 0$. For $P\not\equiv 0$ I think it's true though. To prove it, you should try proving that if a polynomial of $n$ variables is zero on an "$n$-dimensional cube", it's zero everywhere.

Comment: Oh, I think I forgot the special case. Let me try.

Comment: Already anwered: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25513/zariski-closed-sets-in-cn-are-of-measure-0.